# Questions about Virtual Machine's "Plan" in Azure (Terraform)

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, terraform-provider-azure

I'm new to Azure and Terraform, but I've inherited a set of Terraform configs and modules from someone who left my organization. I've been tasked with changing a project's VMs to CIS-hardened versions, which require me to add a "plan" block to one of our VM-provisioning modules:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm-windows" {
  count                         = "${(((var.vm_os_id != "" && var.is_windows_image == "true") || contains(list("${var.vm_os_simple}","${var.vm_os_offer}"), "WindowsServer")) && var.data_disk == "false") ? var.nb_instances : 0}"
  name                          = "${var.vm_hostname}${count.index}"
  location                      = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name           = "${var.resource_group_name}"
  availability_set_id           = "${azurerm_availability_set.vm.id}"
  vm_size                       = "${var.vm_size}"
  network_interface_ids         = ["${element(azurerm_network_interface.vm.*.id, count.index)}"]
  delete_os_disk_on_termination = "${var.delete_os_disk_on_termination}"

  storage_image_reference {
    id        = "${var.vm_os_id}"
    publisher = "${var.vm_os_id == "" ? coalesce(var.vm_os_publisher, module.os.calculated_value_os_publisher) : ""}"
    offer     = "${var.vm_os_id == "" ? coalesce(var.vm_os_offer, module.os.calculated_value_os_offer) : ""}"
    sku       = "${var.vm_os_id == "" ? coalesce(var.vm_os_sku, module.os.calculated_value_os_sku) : ""}"
    version   = "${var.vm_os_id == "" ? var.vm_os_version : ""}"
  }
  # this is what I added
  plan {
    name       = "${var.vm_os_id == "" ? coalesce(var.vm_os_sku, module.os.calculated_value_os_sku) : ""}"
    publisher  = "${var.vm_os_id == "" ? coalesce(var.vm_os_publisher, module.os.calculated_value_os_publisher) : ""}"
    product    = "${var.vm_os_id == "" ? coalesce(var.vm_os_offer, module.os.calculated_value_os_offer) : ""}"
  }

  ...
}
```

Since the module is meant to be generic (i.e., usable by projects that have plan-less and plan-needing VMs), I need to know more about this "plan" block.

- What is it and where can I read more about it? (It seems to be a hard thing to Google properly; e.g., "azure virtual machine plan" yields pricing information.)
- Is it appropriate to leave the block in place for VMs that don't necessarily need it?

The only documentation I've seen so far is [Terraform's scant information on the block](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine.html#plan). It doesn't give much information (not even the argument names), and I don't know how to cross-reference Terraform constructs with Azure's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This block is needed when you create custom marketplace image vms (like barracuda firewalls, or trendmicro servers, etc). basically anything that is not provided by microsoft (for the most part). (https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2016/06/30/deploying-azure-marketplace-vms-via-arm-templates/ or this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/faq/)
2. no, it is not appropriate to do that, you need some sort of condition to include that block. or just have 2 templates, one with the block and one without it.